# What are the advantages of casting Flame Strike over Fireball?

Tags: spells, balance, adnd-1e

Outside of the classes the spells are available to, what is the advantage to using Flame Strike over Fireball in **AD&D 1st Edition**?  Many of the advantages I'm used to seeing later editions (mixed damage type, lack of treasure destruction) aren't apparent in the original version of the spell.  It may be that the only advantage is that Flame Strike is castable by Clerics, which may be an acceptable answer.

What advantages, if any does casting Flame Strike have over Fireball?

Answer (score 3):

### Clerics cannot cast Fireball

That is really the biggest advantage of *Flame Strike* over *Fireball*. Clerics not only get it later (5th) but they have no access to *Fireball* (3rd) at all. *Flame Strike* doesn't scale with the cleric's level, while *Fireball* does (+1d6 per level). So it would be every cleric's *wet dream* to be able to cast *Fireball*.

Magic Users get the cake here. Clerics get a candy to make up for it.

### Physics

Not only that, but *Fireball* also comes with *physics*, explaining how things will combust, how the flames expand and all of that, which is absent from *Flame Strike*. Things like *"impacts upon a material body"*, or *"the burst will generally conform to the shape of the area in which it occurs"*, forces the caster to think twice before sending a fireball flying towards his enemies, which might have a high possibility of also hurting her allies.

To clarify, casting fireball in any area that couldnt fit the cubic explosion would make it expand beyond the intended area, potentially hurting allies or innocent standbys. It was quite common for magic users to cast it inside a dungeon room or corridor and incinerate themselves and their allies.

All of that is absent in *Flame Strike*, making it safer to cast.

Comment: @GcL note that 4d8 isn't entirely accurate as it would have a different distribution than 8d8/2

Comment: @OganM AD&D didn't do divide by two for half damage all the time.  Sometimes, it listed half the number of dice.

Comment: @ShadowKras I mistakenly thought the answer was for 5e upon first reading.  Erroneous comments have been removed.

Comment: @ShadowKras - That's not just "generally used", it's RAW.  AD&D PHB, p.73: "The area which is covered by the fireball is a total volume of roughly 33,000 cubic feet". (Citation taken from a blog post; I don't have a PHB available to verify it.) That's potentially _very_ dangerous if you're casting in a dungeon and haven't fully explored what's on the other side of the target area, so you don't know how much of that 33,000 cubic foot volume can go that way vs. how much will be coming back at you!

Comment: I know it is raw, but I also know many GMs didnt stop the game to calculate that. There was an article in the dragon magazine about that.

Comment: Maybe it isnt clear, but some guy (the other answer) was arguing about my answer thinking it was about 5e dnd. Comments have been removed and I will soon remove mine as well so it doesn't confuse any more people.

Answer (score 3):

## *Flame strike* cannot be blocked, and doesn't ruin money.

The advantages the original flame strike had were:

- Rolls d8 for damage
- Can't be blocked by an object getting in the way
- Doesn't melt soft metals and light items on fire

### *Flame strike* has higher damage until level 8 *fireball*

*Flame strike* damage output is 6d8.  *Fireball* does 1d6 per caster level.  A caster of *fireball* needs to be a level 8 before max damage of *fireball* is equal to that of *flame strike*.

### *Flame strike* has better precision

It makes a column of flame down on the exact spot called for by the caster.  *Fireball* has to be directed with a pointed finger and the range and height called out by the caster.

### Downsides of *fireball* that *flame strike* does not suffer:

#### *Fireball* can be blocked on the way to the destination.

An object in between where the wizard aims the *fireball* and his finger will cause the *fireball* to detonate early.  *Flame strike* does not have this limitation.

#### *Fireball* melts gold

*Fireball* has the problem with wreckin a lot of the material wealth it's area.  *Flame strike* does not have the same problem.

#### *Fireball* can backfire

A *fireball* conforms to the area it's confined in filling in it's entire volume.  This can inadvertently fill the space the wizard or her allies are in if the target space was small and the *fireball* spills back into the area from which it was cast.

Comment: In first edition, *Flame Strike* was 6d8, not 8d8.

Comment: @ShadowKras thanks. I didn't have my book in front of me.

Comment: Clerics learn flame strike at 9th level. By then, Magic Users have 9d6 fireballs while Clerics get 6d8 flame strikes. In every possible scenario, fireballs outputs more damage.

Comment: @ShadowKras I agree assuming casters of equal level. I'll see about reword that part to make the point more clear.

Comment: I dont think its possible for a 8th level cleric to ever cast flame strike. So, there is no realistic situation where flame strike will be more powerful than fireball.

Comment: @ShadowKras Flame strike will be more powerful than fireball cast by a wizard under 8th level.

Comment: That is **also wrong**. The average of a 8th level fireball is 28, the average of a 9th level flamestrike is 27.

Comment: @ShadowKras it's only wrong if assuming aveage damage.  The max damage is equal.

Comment: "Doesn't melt soft metals and light items on fire" This is mostly incorrect, although items have a better chance of saving vs. "magical fire" than against "fireball" (DMG p. 80-1). Flame strike is even listed as an example of magical fire for saving throw purposes.